# how to get selected image from PhotoAlbum and how can i save it in Application document directory?

Tags: iphone

in my iOS application, how to get selected image from PhotoAlbum and how can i save it in Application document directory.

Comment: Have you tried and also do you search in google?

Comment: Must visit http://bit.ly/11cIrNt ,http://bit.ly/10fB2A7. will be very helpful to you

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the help of [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class)

```
-(void)showImagePicker
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];        
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;  
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
}
```

Now Handle user's selected image with following delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];//Do whatever you want to do with your image.
}
```

For more clerity how things work please go through [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPhone_Camera_Application_%28Xcode_4%29)

Hope this helps.